# PHP FormData XMLHttpRequest $_FILES empty, but $_POST gives raw full file encoded

Tags: php, file, xmlhttprequest, multipartform-data

I'm trying to upload file via AJAX, the question is about why $_FILES empty ?

Sample of javascript

```
var formData = new FormData();
var fili = document.getElementById( divID ).files.length;
for (var x = 0; x < fili; x++) { formData.append( "fii" , $("#"+divID).prop("files")[x]); }

var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(); xhr.open("POST", "/uboxhr.php", true);
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xhr.send(formData);
```

in my PHP

```
var_dump($_POST); // -->> I GET stuff like FULL RAW encoded 1�UV[(�c2����
var_dump($_FILES); // -->> Is EMPTY
```

**How Can I get $_FILES to populate ???**

I tried

```
xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'multipart/form-data');
```

but no luck, still same

I also tried

```
var_dump($_FILES['fii']);
```

this case says "`Undefined index: fii`"

Answer (score 0):

!!! I found it :)

the moment I remove this line

```
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
```

all is good !

Comment: I was about to say that you could leave the Content-Type undefined to let the browser handle the file submit itself. Good job on finding it!

Comment: @Stefmachine thanks, had you experience file.type (usually image/png...) with sending file from newest iPhones ? the `$("#"+divID).prop("files")[x].type` is empty

Comment: I haven't experienced that specific case, but I found out that sometimes on different browsers the 'type' property is just not set for some files. I had a project where I had to upload excel files and the file.type was undefined (or null?).

It seems like a not very reliable source for mime type validation. It can sucks when you want to do some cool front-end tricks, but at the end of the day you should never trust your front-end input and always validate from the back-end.